# Value errors for joins in pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, join

I have two dataframes, which I'm trying to join. The table, students, just has unique ID and age of every student. The table attendance defines for each date whether a given student was present or not. I'd like to find out what percentage of the time each age was in attendance, (ie 17 year olds were there 50% of the time.) Before I can do such a groupby aggregation, I need to execute a join.

```py
import pandas as pd

students = {'age':[17,17,16,18,15,19], 'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6]}
attendance = {'date':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2], 'attendance':[1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1], 'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6]}


a = pd.DataFrame(attendance)
s = pd.DataFrame(students)

s.join(other=a, on=['id','id'], how='outter')
```

The error I'm receiving says, `ValueError: len(left_on) must equal the number of levels in the index of "right"`. However, I don't understand the issue.

How should I adjust this code to achieve the desired effect?

Edit:
It works just fine with `pd.merge` but I'm still not clear why the above doesn't execute properly?

```py
pd.merge(left=s, right=a, left_on='id', right_on='id',how='right')
```

Comment: Typo: `outter` should be `outer`.

Comment: I caught that a moment ago, the error is triggered before this argument is observed by the interpreter, apparently,

Comment: From the documentation of the `on` parameter: **If multiple values given, the other DataFrame must have a MultiIndex.** There's no MultiIndex in the `a` dataframe.

Comment: just pass `on='id'`, not a list

Comment: Or specify the index columns when creating each dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join assume you have the same length on your columns.
Use merge instead.

**Code below:**

```
import pandas as pd

students = {'age':[17,17,16,18,15,19], 'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6]}
attendance = {'date':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2], 'attendance':[1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1], 'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6]}


a = pd.DataFrame(attendance)
s = pd.DataFrame(students)

s.merge(right=a, on='id', how='outer')
```

**Output:**

```
    age  id  date  attendance
0    17   1     1           1
1    17   1     2           1
2    17   2     1           0
3    17   2     2           1
4    16   3     1           1
5    16   3     2           0
6    18   4     1           1
7    18   4     2           0
8    15   5     1           1
9    15   5     2           1
10   19   6     1           1
11   19   6     2           1
```

Comment: Why would the column lengths need to be the same (given the existence of different types of joins)?